# client disconnect after one message in mqtt

Tags: python, arduino, mqtt

```
import time

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Conectando al Servidor - " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("Valve_OC")
    client.subscribe("Medir")


def on_message(client, userdata, message):  # The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
    global message_received
    time.sleep(1)
    message_received=str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("received message =", message_received)
    valor_mensaje= int(float(message_received))
    #el potenciometro va de 0 a 1023, simulamos que es el sensor de temperatura
    if (valor_mensaje<=300): #apertura 100%
        print("abrir completamente la valvula")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,100")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        client.disconnect()
 
    elif (valor_mensaje>300 and valor_mensaje<=600): #apertura 60%
        print("abrir valvula al 60")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,60")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        client.disconnect()
   
    elif (valor_mensaje>600 and valor_mensaje<800): #apertura 30%
        print("abrir al 30")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,30")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        client.disconnect()
  
    elif (valor_mensaje>=800) : #cerrar
        print("cerrar valvula")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Cerrar")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        client.disconnect()

def on_publish(client, obj, mid):
    print("Mensaje: " + str(mid))


def on_subscribe(client, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))


def on_log(client, obj, level, string):
    print(f"Log: {string}")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
client.on_log = on_log



client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)

client.loop_forever()
```

Hey,
I'm trying to receive messages from the topic "medir" and put some conditions to send other messages to the topic "Valve_OC". the thing is that I want to receive all messages from the topic like in loop, but after receiving the first message the client disconnect. I have put the line client.disconnect() in each "if" because if I don't put it the client send me messages from the topic "valve_OC" I don't know why. any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is just how MQTT v3.x works, you will receive **ALL** messages on a given topic that you subscribe to. That includes messages sent by the same client.

So since you have subscribed to both `Medir` and `Valve_OC` you are always going to get all those messages.

So you are going to have to remove the calls to discontect.

If you don't want to receive messages on the `Valve_OC` topic you either need to not subscribe to it or use MQTT v5.

With MQTT v5 it is possible to set a flag when subscribing that prevents the broker from delivering messages sent by the same client. Both this requires both the broker and the client library to support both MQTT v5 for it to work.

E.g.

```
client.subscribe('org/common',no_local=True)
```